# How to find out if a tree node is an indirect descendant of a current node?

Tags: node.js, tree

I have a tree structure. Each node has the following fields:

- _id
- nestingLevel
- oldersAnscestorId
- ... other values

if I'm given a node **A** and a node **B** where `B.nestingLevel > A.nestingLevel` how can I find out that **B** is a descendant of **A**?

I was thinking about using uuid version 3 that uses namespace to somehow find the relatedness, but not currently sure how it can help me.
Another idea was to use some sort of a dynamically generated key that would accept different values like `nestingLevel`, `_id` of a deeper nested node and maybe something else to find out their relatedness.

**UPDATE**

I don't think that traversing is a good option as I have this in a microservice architecture and traversing would mean communicating with another service. Moving the tree to another service is also not an option as I have to use my current service to query the database

Comment: Just walk up the tree?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, sorry, I didn't mention this initially I have a microservice architecture and traversing the tree is not currently possible

Answer (score 0):

I would add an array storing some unique hash of all parent nodes in the node and just check using it. This can be optimized, of course.